# Imaplib with GMail offsets uids

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib

I'm querying my gmail inbox using pythons ImapLib with a range parameter, but my returned uids are offset from what I request. My request is as follows:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.login(USER, PASS)
# Choose the inbox for finding mail
M.select('INBOX')
rv, data = M.uid("search", None, '29540:*')
```

This returns a single UID, 29725.

If I subtract 421 (found by trial and error) from the beginning range I get the full list of uids from from 29540 to 29725. I am stumped. Could it be that it is not using UID in this range and is somehow having problems with deleted emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `M.uid` simply specifies that the return value will be UID's, so it is still necessary to specify that the parameters sent will be UID's and not message ID's. This fixes it:

```
rv, data = M.uid("search", None, 'UID', '29540:*')
```

Answer (score 0):

rv, data = M.uid("search", None, '(UID 29540:*)')

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation

Comment: but it has difference, the above answer didn't worked for me